# $A^2 - B^2$ is an invertible matrix and $A^5 = B^5$ and $A^3B^2 = A^2B^3$ . Then what is the determinant of the matrix $A^3 + B^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A,B$ are two $3 \times 3$ real-matrices with following three properties.

1. $A^2 - B^2$ is an invertible matrix
2. $A^5 = B^5$
3. $A^3B^2 = A^2B^3$

Then what is the determinant of the matrix $A^3 + B^3$ ?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ could be diagonal matrices with fifth roots of unity (you didn't say real matrices).

Comment: You can't factor things like $A^2-B^2=(A+B)(A-B)$ if $A$ and $B$ don't commute. Similarly, $A^3B^2=A^2B^3$ you should factor as $A^2(A-B)B^2=0$, not $A^2B^2(A-B)$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Currently, (3) says $A^3B^2=A^2B^3$, not $A^3B^2=B^3A^2$.

Comment: Ouch, didn't notice that. Deleting the previous comment, sorry for the mistake. You still do get $A^5 - A^3B^2 = B^5 - A^2B^3$ and therefore $A^3(A^2-B^2) = -(A^2-B^2)B^3$ from this factorization, though, so $A^3$ and $-B^3$ are similar matrices.

Comment: Oops. The 2x2 counterexample does not really work. $A^2B^3=A^3B^2$ fails when $B=A^{-1}$ (in my mind I saw a commutator relation). Anyway, the answer is either zero or unknown.

Comment: If you get that both $A$ and $B$ are the zero matrix, anonymous, then you know you've done something wrong, since that contradicts invertibility of $A^2-B^2$.

Comment: Yes you are correct . That proves those three conditions will imply $AB \neq BA$.@Grey Myerson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V=\mathbb R^3$. The condition $A^5=B^5$ implies that $A^5V=B^5V$. Since $A$ is $3\times 3$, the descending chain $V\supseteq AV\supseteq A^2V\supseteq\cdots$ must have been stabilised at $A^3V$ and the similar is true for $B^3V$. Therefore from $A^5V=B^5V$ we get $W:=A^3V=B^3V$.

Furthermore, as the descending chains have been stabilised, both $A$ and $B$ are automorphisms on the invariant subspace $W$. The condition $A^3B^2=A^2B^3$ thus implies that $A=B$ on $W$. As $A^2-B^2$ is invertible, $W$ must be zero. Hence $A^3V=B^3V=0$, i.e., $A^3=B^3=0$. Consequently $\det(A^3+B^3)=0$.

**Remark.** Actually, for any number $c$, “$\det(A^3+B^3)=c$” is a correct answer, because **no** matrices $A$ and $B$ can satisfy all three given conditions in the first place. Suppose the contrary. By our previous argument, $A$ and $B$ must be nilpotent. Since the matrices are $3\times3$, the ranks of $A^2$ and $B^2$ are at most one. Therefore the rank of $A^2-B^2$ is at most two. Hence $A^2-B^2$ is singular, but this is a violation of the first condition.

However, if we change the first condition to “$A-B$ is invertible”, there are feasible pairs of $A$ and $B$, such as
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&2&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0&0&0}
\text{ and }B=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 1&0&0}.
$$
In this case, our previous argument still applies and we may conclude that $A^3=B^3=0$ and $\det(A^3+B^3)=0$.

Comment: How do we know $A-B$ is invertible? Also, in the "concrete example", $A^2-B^2$ is not invertible.

Comment: [The preceding comment applied to an earlier version of the answer.]

Comment: Nice! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 5):

$A$ and $B$ are real $3\times3$ matrices, so their eigenvalue polynomials are cubic and hence have at least one real zero. Let $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$ be an eigenvalue of $B$, and $x\in\Bbb{R}^3$ be the corresponding eigenvector. Then
$$
A^5x=B^5x=\lambda^5x.\tag{1}
$$
We also have
$$
\lambda^3A^2x=(A^2B^3)x=A^3B^2x=\lambda^2A^3x.\tag{2}
$$
Apply $A^3$ to both sides of $(2)$, and use $(1)$ to arrive at
$$
\lambda^8x=A^3(\lambda^3A^2x)=A^3(\lambda^2A^3x)=\lambda^2A^6x=\lambda^7Ax.\tag{3}
$$

If $\lambda\neq0$ then $(3)$ implies that $Ax=\lambda x$ also. This violates the first assumption as then
$$(A^2-B^2)x=\lambda^2x-\lambda^2x=0.$$

We are left with the case $\lambda=0$. Again, by $(1)$ we see that $A^5x=0$. Because $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix this implies (think Jordan canonical form) that already $A^3x=0$.

We have shown that $(A^3+B^3)x=0$ for a non-zero vector $x$, and can conclude that $\det(A^3+B^3)=0$.

Comment: If calling upon Jordan canonical forms is not to your liking, you can use Cayley-Hamilton instead. A bit like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1624252/11619) and many other places on our site. The minimal polynomial of $A$ gives a recurrence relation satisfied by the vectors $A^{k+\ell}x, \ell=0,1,2,3$, all $k$. Work backwards to show that first $A^4x$ must be the zero vector and then also $A^3x=0$.

Comment: If somebody finds a better on-site reference to this property, please share. I don't do enough linear algebra, and my search-fu is apparently weak today.

Comment: May be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1019978/11619)?

Comment: The $A^3x=0$ also can be seen as follows: consider the subspace spanned by $A$ and $x$ and the minimal polynomial $p(T)$ of the restriction of $A$ to it. It divides $T^5$ and has degree at most $3$, so it divides $T^3$.

Comment: @Bart, $A$ is a matrix, $x$ is a vector, so what does "the subspace spanned by $A$ and $x$" mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I mean the smallest $A$-stable subspace containing $x$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why started with a real eigenvalue? Actually you proved that the only eigenvalue of B is 0, so B is nilpotent. It follows that A is nilpotent and thus their third powers are 0.

Comment: That is a very good question @user26857 ! I really don't know :-). I was building the answer as I made progress (possibly a personal weakness of mine), and should have re-examined the argument. You see, at the time I thought I had counterexamples consisting of $2\times2$ matrices (later I found the error in it). Therefore the solution had to be specific to $3\times3$, et cetera.